# python, selenium - python dont execute the else - statement

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need the the search Result from any search term from Google. I wrote an if-statement where it looks first if the searchResult is true, then print it.
Otherwise print 0.
I know it says that it can't find the element, but i want to say to my script if he cant find the element, type 0. So as the else statement.
Code:

```
 elif inputOfUser == '':
        if chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultStats"]') == True:
            table.update_cell(row, 5, chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultStats"]').text[:-27])
        else:
            table.update_cell(row, 5, str(0))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/TechDynasty/Desktop/Programmieren/Allintitle/Test.py", line 39, in <module>
    print(chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultStats"]'))
  File "C:\Users\TechDynasty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 385, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\TechDynasty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\TechDynasty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\TechDynasty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="resultStats"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

driver.find_element_by_xpath will throw NoSuchElementException if it's asked to find something which doesn't exist, however driver.find_elements_by_xpath will return None in the same scenario:

```
        elements = chrome.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultStats"]')
        if elements is not None:
            table.update_cell(row, 5, elements[0].text[:-27])
        else:
            table.update_cell(row, 5, str(0))
```

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: Error

Answer (score 0):

As you want to look first if the searchResult is true and then print it or otherwise print 0, you can put the `if` block within `try-except {}` block as follows :

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
// lines of code        
elif inputOfUser == '':
    try :
        if chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultStats"]') == True:
            table.update_cell(row, 5, chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultStats"]').text[:-27])
    except NoSuchElementException:
        table.update_cell(row, 5, str(0))
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException is undefind

Comment: @KaanDev Updated the answer with the import let me know the status

Comment: Works fine Thanks.
But now it doesnt update the cell, when there is a value from SearchResult

Comment: @KaanDev My answer was to provide you the logic to execute the `else` block. For the value updating with `table.update_cell(row, 5, chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultStats"]').text[:-27])` can you raise a new ticket please?

Comment: no it didnt helped me alot now i know how to catch the error and update the cell with a 0, but the following term with a search result couldnt be updated into the following cell